# How do I remove a word and what follows after it in an R vector?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, vector

I'm new to R and I need to remove a word and what follows it in quotation marks from a vector in a dataframe.

Here's a bit of what I have:

```
c("'character': 'Ted the Bellhop', 'credit_id': '52fe420dc3a36847f80001b7', 2",
  "'character': 'Man', 'credit_id': '52fe420dc3a36847f800018b', 2",
  "'character': 'Angela', 'credit_id': '52fe420dc3a36847f8000183', 1")
```

I'm working with a large dataset so I need to find a way to be able to remove 'character': and what comes after it ('Ted the Bellhop', 'Man', etc.)

I tried using fromJSON for this but it wouldn't work so that's why I chose to remove things manually. 
I was able to remove a field with  only numbers in it using:

```
x <- gsub("'cast_id': [[:digit:]]+,", "", x)
```

Comment: *"Here's a bit of what I have:"* I'm not quite clear on the format of your data. Is it a named vector? A `data.frame`? A `list`? Can you please provide sample data using `dput`?

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I fixed it in the question. Each line is supposed to be a value in the vector.

Comment: That's better, but it's still not really clear what you're expecting the output to be. Your code attempt contains a `'cast_id'` but your example vector doesn't contain that string. Either way, please take a look at the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
x <- gsub("'character': '[^']*',", "", x)
```

It's pretty much the same thing you did for the `cast_id` field, except it will remove values matching the regular expression `'[^']*'` instead of digits. Read this as:

- `[^']`: any character other than `'`
- `[^']*`: same as above, repeated 0 or more times
- `'[^']*'`: same as above, wrapped in single quotes

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not clear on your expected output; is this what you're after?

```
sub("^.+\\s(?='credit_id')", "", ss, perl = T)
#[1] "'credit_id': '52fe420dc3a36847f80001b7', 2"
#[2] "'credit_id': '52fe420dc3a36847f800018b', 2"
#[3] "'credit_id': '52fe420dc3a36847f8000183', 1"
```

Or perhaps this?

```
sub("^.+\\s('credit_id': '\\w+'),.+$", "\\1", ss, perl = T)
#[1] "'credit_id': '52fe420dc3a36847f80001b7'"
#[2] "'credit_id': '52fe420dc3a36847f800018b'"
#[3] "'credit_id': '52fe420dc3a36847f8000183'"
```

---

### Sample data

```
ss <- c("'character': 'Ted the Bellhop', 'credit_id': '52fe420dc3a36847f80001b7', 2",
  "'character': 'Man', 'credit_id': '52fe420dc3a36847f800018b', 2",
  "'character': 'Angela', 'credit_id': '52fe420dc3a36847f8000183', 1")
```